# Cannot ssh out of RP with fresh Raspbian install

Tags: ssh

I just installed the latest Raspbian onto a new RP with seemingly no issues, then did `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` as sudo.

The machine seems fine and quite happy on my network - I can ping it and ssh into it, and I can ping out of it and use http.

But I can't ssh *out* of it.  My first hint was that I couldn't use ssh mode in github, but then I tried a server I own and I couldn't get to that either.

Looking at `/var/logs` I see no evidence of any relevant error.  And `ssh` is enabled in raspi-config.

Comment: No progress whatsoever.  I updated and upgraded everything.  I tested the power supply, and then replaced it with a much beefier one.  Really frustrating...

Comment: Please give us the output of: `ssh yoursever -vvvv`, replace `yourserver` with whatever server you've testet with. Add all options that are usualy need to connected to the server. Add `-vvvv` as it will give you (and us) more output what ssh is trying to do. Once you have the output: [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/47761/edit) your question and add the information

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us any error messages from ssh?

Also, even if you can ping it on the network and reach in via ssh, that doesn't mean it can reach outside. Are you using Network Address Translation, is it connected via Wireless LAN, is it connected via ethernet to a router, or is it connected directly to a PC of yours?

/etc/ssh/ssh_config is a relevant configuration file, by the way. Maybe some obvious errors in there.

Also, when trying to just get ssh working, I sometimes delete everything in ~/.ssh to get a clean slate.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was almost three years ago so that whole setup is long decommissioned.  If I recall correctly, it turned out to be that there was a known bug involving my (common) wireless router and the RP3, so when I went to a wired connection, the problem ceased.

Answer (score -1):

did you enable ssh in raspi-config

sudo raspi-config,
advances options, 
ssh,
enable, 
reboot.

This might work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did check that - and ssh comes turned on out of the box, I didn't have to turn it on.  I'll add that to the original question.

Comment: This enables ssh **into** the RPi, not **out** of it!